# When does a set sequence admit a limit?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $B_n \subset X$ be a set sequence in $X$, then we say that $B_n$ has a limit $B$ if
$$
B=\limsup_{n\to \infty}B_n=\liminf_{n\to \infty} B_n
$$
where $\limsup_{n\to \infty}B_n=\cap_{k=1}^\infty \cup_{j=k}^\infty B_n$  and  $\liminf_{n\to \infty}B_n=\cup_{k=1}^\infty \cap_{j=k}^\infty B_n$.

**QUESTION 1** Are there sufficient conditions on the sets $B_n$ such that a limit set $B$ exists?

I would be tempted to say that a sufficient condition is the following:

**(S.1)** $\forall x\in B$ there exists $n_x$ and a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq x}$ such that $x_n \in B_n$, for $n=n_x,n_x+1,\ldots$, and $d(x_n,x)\to 0$.

However this can be true only in the case where the set theoretical definition of limit set also admits a topological characterization, which may fail to be true.

For example, in the trivial case of $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $d$ the Euclidean metric, we could choose $B_n=\{1/n\}$ and have $B_{n}\cap B_{n+k}=\emptyset$, for any integer $k\geq 1$, thus $\liminf_{n\to \infty}B_n =\emptyset$; consequently, defining $B=\{0\}$, we would have that $B\neq \liminf_{n\to \infty}B_n$, whence we could not conclude $B=\lim_{n\to\infty}B_n$ even if the choice $x_n=1/n$ satisfies $x_n\in B_n$ and $x_n \to 0$.

**QUESTION 2** would the following be sufficient?

**(S.2)** Condition **(S.1)** is satisfied and the sets $B_n$, $\limsup_{n\to \infty}B_n$ and $\liminf_{n\to \infty} B_n$ are nonempty and connected, but not singletons.

Comment: I believe $\liminf B_n = \limsup B_n$ is equivalent to for every $x\in X$ either $x\in B_n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, or $x\notin B_n$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. I'm not sure this can be captured with the metric.